# GAE: use flexible environment or standard environment in a project with processing MS Word files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am new to GCP but I need a help what to choose: **Flex** or **Standard environment**.
The app I've developed (Python 2.7) is dealing with:

1. Loading MS Word files from user (online).
2. Keeping them in storage (should be Google cloud or file system?).
3. Processing them against predefined DB entries (MySQL).
4. Modified file is sent back to user/client.

Since standard env. has some restrictions ([comparing page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_environments)) as

> Writing to local disk: "No" in standard env.

So, should I use rather *flexible environment to load and store MS Word files*?

Any other aspects you may mention concerning the use of any of the environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) designed to help you choose your environment. The key differences are highlighted [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#similarities_and_key_differences).

To answer you specific question, both environment are capable of doing what you want but in different ways. App Engine provide file storage with [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/), you can easily store your MS Word files here.

I am unsure what you mean by "processing them against ... MySQL", but any standard data parsing, importing, and exporting are available with Cloud SQL which is accessible from both App Engine environments.

I would suggest trying Google App Engine Standard if you want it easier to manage; if you want more control, then Google App Engine Flex is a better choice.

Comment: Ying, the document you've mentioned sais: `Standard env. does not support installing third-party binaries`. Is it related to 3-d party libraries install limit? Since I've problem even with predefined `MySQLdb` library - http://joxi.ru/zAN570lfBV8472 (when launching my app at App Engine).

Comment: That's right, if you want to use third party libraries, you would need Flex. But your use case doesn't seem like it would need third party libraries. We provide a Cloud SQL solution that works natively with our own App Engine, so you don't really needs third party libraries.

Comment: Ying, thank you. I'd turn your attention to my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52290122/1230477).

Comment: Yeah the first answer in that question is correct. So to clarify, we have ["built-in" third party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) and we also allow you to [upload your own library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) with certain restrictions. So obviously it will work because the library is uploaded to App Engine along with your application code and it counts in your file count quota.

Comment: Ying, I am in dispare about  the connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud console... see my last comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311029/gcp-at-the-standard-environment-mysql-db-connection-refused?noredirect=1#comment91586972_52311029). Can you check my files inside of Google Cloud Platform and say what's wrong?

Comment: please could you check my [4th Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311029/gcp-at-the-standard-environment-mysql-db-connection-refused?noredirect=1) about db connection and comment it?